# Git for web development conceptual help needed

Tags: git, workflow, dvcs

I need some advice on how to structure the workflow of our local source-management/development and deployment.
We're a team of 3 developers and 2 web designers (templates/css) and currently work directly on remote FTP Servers.
So we have development servers and production servers.
I now want to change all that by using git on our intranet server to develop and deploy.

The difficult part is how to structure the development.
My first idea was that every developer uses a remote smb/nfs mount with the git repositories on our development server who runs Apache2 / MySQL.

Pro: Every developer would have the same testing environment (Apache2 on Linux, Imagemagick etc.)

Con: Remote SMB or NFS mounts are just too slow to work with git :(

Now I don't really know how to handle this problem the best way.

Every developer could have their own development server on their local machines BUT this would mix Windows, Mac and Linux Servers.

I hope my problem comes through.

How do you develop with git in the Web/PHP world?

Comment: Actually, in a fast network (and with fast servers) NFS can be even faster than a local disk.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a source control problem. It sounds like you should look into something like [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/).